# Qt: Insert character every x characters

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, qtcore, chunks

I am creating a little application in which I create a SHA1 hash with php and use the `chunk_split` function in php to insert a "|" every x characters.

Is there something similar? Or how would one split the string and insert a character there?

PHP Code:

> substr(strtoupper(chunk_split(sha1("this is my super secure test application"), 5, "-")), 0, 29);

How can I do this with Qt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write something like this:

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>

int main()
{
    const int step = 3;
    const char mychar = 'x';
    QString myString = "FooBarBaz";
    for (int i = step; i <= myString.size(); i+=step+1)
        myString.insert(i, mychar);
    qDebug() << myString;
    return 0;
}
```

#### main.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = main
QT = core
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

#### Build and Run

```
qmake && make && ./main
```

#### Output

```
"FooxBarxBazx"
```

See the documentation of the insert method [in here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstring.html#insert-4).